# I added my C# Programm to the windows Registry how to get the File i rightclicked on in my code?

Tags: c#, windows, visual-studio, registry

I coded a simple hello word Programm in Visual Studio with C# and added it to the Windows Context Menue. How to get the File i rightclicked on to my Programm and work with it?

Comment: What exactly do you want to happen to the file when you right click on it? It's not very clear what you're asking.

Comment: I just want to work with the file i right clicked. First i just want to show the name of the righclicked file and then i will look further, but for now thats enough.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [adding my program to right-click menu](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6179562/adding-my-program-to-right-click-menu)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This filename you can get as arg in your entry point (static void Main(string[] args)). Just to check I added context menu item and assosiate it with my app. App code:

```
    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        foreach(var a in args)
        {
            Console.WriteLine(a);
        }
        Console.ReadKey();
    }
```

As result I get name of file I called menu on.
But you should add key this way - "pathToExe %1", this is important thing.

[image]